# How to pass checkbox value 0 or 1 in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            url: $('#MAINURL').val() + "admin/ajax/ajax_homedisplay.php",
            data: [
                {name: 'mode', value: 'update'}
                , {name: 'slider', value: htmlEncode($('#slider').val())}
                , {name: 'welcomebox', value: htmlEncode($('#welcomebox').val())}
                , {name: 'servicebox', value: htmlEncode($('#servicebox').val())}

            ],
```

here slider,welcomebox, servicebox is a checkbox i want to pass 0 or 1 value if checkbox is checked thn insert 1 or else 0.

Currently it is insert only 1 weather it is checked or not it is insert only 1.

I want to insert 1 when checkbox is checked and when checkbox is unchecked thn insert 0.

Comment: So use `is(":checked")`

Comment: where plz add in my code @u_mulder

Comment: so your form design code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this,

```
$.ajax({
            url: $('#MAINURL').val() + "admin/ajax/ajax_homedisplay.php",
            data: [
                {name: 'mode', value: 'update'}
                , {name: 'slider', value: htmlEncode($('#slider').val())}
                , {name: 'welcomebox', value: htmlEncode($('#welcomebox').attr('checked'))}
                , {name: 'servicebox', value: htmlEncode($('#servicebox').attr('checked'))}

            ],
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: in this case it will return true or false, when you want to return 1/0 you need to use ternary operator to send data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
{name: 'welcomebox', value: $('#welcomebox').is( ":checked" )? 1 : 0}
```

Or:

```
{name: 'welcomebox', value: $('#welcomebox').attr( "checked" )? 1 : 0}
```

And jsperf shows that the following way is the fastest:

```
{name: 'welcomebox', value: document.getElementById('welcomebox').checked? 1 : 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var welcomechk = 0;
var servicechk =0;

if($('#welcomebox').is(":checked"))
    welcomechk =1;

if($('#servicebox').is(":checked"))
    servicechk =1;  



$.ajax({
            url: $('#MAINURL').val() + "admin/ajax/ajax_homedisplay.php",
            data: [
                {name: 'mode', value: 'update'}
                , {name: 'slider', value: htmlEncode($('#slider').val())}
                , {name: 'welcomebox', value: htmlEncode(welcomechk)}
                , {name: 'servicebox', value: htmlEncode(servicechk)}

            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var day = document.getElementById('checkboxId');

if(day.checked == true){
    var VarName = "1";
}
if(day.checked == false){
    var VarName = "0";
}
```